# Python 3 split string multiple times

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, split

Text file input:

10G/Host_IP,UID,PWD,Host-Name,15-2-7

10G/Host_IP,UID,PWD,Host-Name,12-2-7

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes("-topmost", True) 
root.withdraw()
file = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()

def _10g_script (params):

    print (type(params))   ## says params is a str


    for items in params:
        params1 = items.split(",")
##    print(IP, UID, PWD, TID, SH_SL_PT)   ## is what I am wanting here, 
                                           ##then I will split the SH_SL_PT
        print (type(params1))  ## says params is a list


with open(file,"r") as fh:
    for lines in fh:
        rate, param = lines.strip().split("/")
        
        if rate == "10G":
            _10g_script(param)
           print (type(param))  ## says param is a str
```

What I am trying to is split the line from the text file the rate and the rest of the parameters, rate and other parameters into separate variables. Pass the rate into the function then split the variable params further into more variables (Host_IP, UID, PWD, Host-Name, SH_SL_PT).

The first split in  is a str and after the split, but when I try the second split it says it is a list.

I have tried join, but it puts every character as its own string with a "," in between characters

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's walk through the code. Your code starts here:

```
with open(file,"r") as fh:
for lines in fh:
    rate, param = lines.strip().split("/")
    
    if rate == "10G":
        _10g_script(param)
       print (type(param))  ## says param is a str
```

We first open the file and then jump into the for loop. This loop splits up the document into lines, and puts these lines into a list that it goes through, meaning that the variable **lines** is a string of one line of the document, and every iteration we go to the next line.

Next we split the our **line** using "/". This split creates a list containing two elements, with lines.strip().split("/") = ["10G","Host_IP,UID,PWD,Host-Name,12-2-7"]. However, on the left side you put two variables, rate and param, so python sets rate = "10G" and param = "Host_IP,UID,PWD,Host-Name,12-2-7".

Going into your function, params as you saw is a string. So when you try to loop through it, python assumes that you want each iteration of your loop to go through a single character.

So, instead of writing the function _10g_script, what you can do is:

```
with open(file,"r") as fh:
for lines in fh:
    rate, param = lines.strip().split("/")
    
    if rate == "10G":
       #IP = "Host_IP", UID = "UID", TID = "TID", SH_SL_PT  
       IP, UID, PWD, TID, SH_SL_PT = param.split(",") 
       print(IP,UID,TID,SH_SL_PT)
```

Then you would do the same for SH_SL_PT, writing:

```
SH,SL,PT = SH_SL_PT.split("-")
```

Wherever you needed that.

Comment: That is better than writing functions for all of the rates, was going to add 1g, and 100g after I got the 10g figured out. This is for telnetting into telecom equipment btw. 10g = 10 gig. I do get an error though when I try     SH,SL,PT = SH_SL_PT.split("_")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Comment: My bad, meant to have SH,SL,PT = SH_SL_PT.split("-"). With the "_", there aren't enough values in the list from our split to go into SH, SL, and PT. I made the edit on the post

Comment: Perfect.. I should have caught that as well